# Django's IntegerRangeField & django-filter's overlap

Tags: postgresql, django-rest-framework, range, django-filter

I'm developing an online database of motion picture filmstocks. We have excellent data on many attributes that can be represented in a search form using checkboxes, e.g., gauge (8mm, Super 8, 16mm, 35mm), type (Reversal, Negative, Positive, Other), & balance (Tungsten, Daylight, Infrared). We lack good data with respect to the years a filmstock was introduced or discontinued. It's unlikely we'll ever seek month and day for this data so I'm using a PostgreSQL IntegerRangeField rather than a DateRangeField.

When people choose to search by years I would like to remove from consideration any stock missing both year of introduction and year discontinued. To that queryset I would like to apply an `overlap` filter. I've been trying to go about it this way–

```
class StockFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Stock
        form = YearsProducedForm
        fields = [
            'company',
            'gauges',
            'chromas',
            'bases',
            'types',
            'usages',
            'balances',
            'years_produced',
        ]
        filter_overrides = {
            IntegerRangeField: {
                'filter_class': filters.NumericRangeFilter,
                'extra': lambda f: {
                    'lookup_expr': 'overlap'
                },
            }
        }


class StockList(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = StockSerializer
    filterset_class = StockFilter

    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.request.query_params['years_produced_min'] or self.request.query_params['years_produced_max']:
            try:
                start = int(self.request.query_params['years_produced_min'])
            except ValueError:
                start = None
            try:
                end =  int(self.request.query_params['years_produced_max'])
            except ValueError:
                end = None
            return Stock.objects.exclude(years_produced__exact=(None, None))
        else:
            return Stock.objects.all()
```

–without success. I've read [in the docs](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/filters.html?highlight=IntegerRangeField#numericrangefilter) that:

> Regular field lookups are available in addition to several containment lookups, including overlap, contains, and contained_by. More details in the Django docs.

> If the lower limit value is provided, the filter automatically defaults to `startswith` as the lookup and `endswith` if only the upper limit value is provided.

The `startswith` behavior is consistent with what I am seeing and I don't understand how to get get the `overlap` lookup if not through `extra`. Grateful for any insights or suggestions, thank you. (Django 3.0.6, Django Rest Framework 3.11.0, Django Filter 2.3.0.)

Comment: Can u provide examples of 'overlap' filter and expected outcomes. The Q is not about films, it is about filter 'overlap' ing. please explain what u need. I'll take alook :)

Comment: PostgreSQL introduced [range types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/rangetypes.html) in 2012's 9.2 release. `overlap` is one of the [operators defined for that type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-range.html). Range field types are supported in [Django itself](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#range-fields) and other key links in the chain such as psycopg2, DRF, & django-filter.

Comment: I am trying to implement a query similar to ```SELECT stock_number, name, lower(years_produced), upper(years_produced)
FROM filmstocks_stock
WHERE years_produced && int4range(1960, NULL) AND NOT (lower(years_produced) IS NULL AND upper(years_produced) IS NULL)
ORDER BY lower(years_produced), upper(years_produced)
;``` using django-filter.